# mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /boot failed: invalid argument mount: mounting /dev/sda6 on /tmp/mount.PPWHGn failed:

Tags: linux, boot, mount, virtual-machine, fstab

After configuring the image using a generalized method, I successfully created a VM. Initially it was started. However, upon attempting to restart the VM or start it after stopping it, I encountered the errors shown below on the Azure serial console.

```
mount: mounting /dev/sd1 on /boot failed: invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev/sd6 on /tmp/mount.PPWHGn failed: No such file or directory
unmount: can't unmount  /boot: Invalid argument

checking filesystems...
e2fsck operational error

e2fsck operational error
Filesystem check requires reboot

Rebooting...
```

What could be the basic reason for this error? How to resolve it? Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda6` ?

Comment: Yes, right it is /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda6. Thank You!